# Discriminant Solutions Calculation Batch File (Square Root)

Tags: batch-file, calculator, equation, square-root

New here but I will try to be short and on the point. I am trying to create a program that has the user input 3 values which the program then proceeds and uses as the A, B and C respectively in the ax^2+bx+c (discriminant = D) and gives you the "solutions" it has (if D>0 then 2 solutions, if D = 0 one "double" solution and if D < 0 it will display that there are no real solutions) . Thing is, no matter how hard i have tried, I cannot come up with a way to calculate the square root later in the process (should the discriminant be positive). I have tried instead of trying to find the square root to raise the discriminant to 1/2 (i.e. D^(1/2)) and no results, maybe i am doing it wrong though

```
:positive
:squareroot
set /p M==%B%*%B%-4*%A%*%C% 
set /a number=%M%, last=2, sqrt=number/last
:next
set /a last=(last+sqrt)/2, sqrt=number/last
if %sqrt% lss %last% goto next
set /a Q=(-%B%+%last%)/2*%A%
set /a R=(-%B%-%last%)/2*%A%
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo The first solution is ~%Q%~ and the second is ~%R%~ !
echo ----------------------------------------------------
pause
goto start
```

After trying and searching on the web, i found the above code which actually somehow manages to calculate the square root of a number, at close approximation (i.e. square root of 9 = 3 BUT square root of 15 also = 3). Nonetheless for the purposes of the project it suits my needs.

Instead of calculating the number the program displays `%B%*%B%-4*%A%*%C%` (instead of the variables, the values the user chose) and then shuts down.

Comment: What's with the `set /p` line? This is no proper syntax and leads to an error. What exactly is it meant to do?

Comment: my mistake, it was supposed to be set /a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'll try to guess, what you try to do. (expanded the example with some variables that obviously got defined somewhere else in your code to make it work).

Your line `set /p M==%B%*%B%-4*%A%*%C%` is nonsense. `set /p` asks the user for input, so you don't want to use `/p`. Variables are set with a simple `=`, not `==` and I think you want the variable to hold the *formula*, not the result. `%B%` is replaced by the value of the variable `B`, probably not, what you want. To escape the percent signs, double them, so the `%M%` would *literally* contain `%B%*%B%-4*%A%*%C%`.
Just set /a `number=%M%` would not work, because you want the variables to be evaluated *here*, so you need another layer of parsing (you can do it with `call`).

```
@echo off
setlocal
:positive
:squareroot
set b=3
set a=4
set c=5

set  "M=%%B%%*%%B%%-4*%%A%%*%%C%%" 
call set /a number=%M%
set /a last=2, sqrt=number/last 

:next
set /a last=(last+sqrt)/2, sqrt=number/last
if %sqrt% lss %last% goto next
set /a Q=(-%B%+%last%)/2*%A%
set /a R=(-%B%-%last%)/2*%A%
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo The first solution is ~%Q%~ and the second is ~%R%~ !
echo ----------------------------------------------------
pause
goto start
```

(Note: I didn't analyze the rest of the code, as it seems to work fine)